# Determine the new zeroes of a function following a series of transformation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots, transformation

The zeroes of the function $y = f(x)$ are $a, b, c.$ What are the new zeroes if that function is transformed into $y = \dfrac{1}{2f(-rx - t)}?$

My solution:  $(a, 0) , (b, 0) , (c, 0)$.

$1)$ Reflection about the $y$ - axis:  $(-a, 0) , (-b, 0) , (-c, 0)$
$2)$ Vertical compression by a factor of $1/2$: no affect $(-a, 0) , (-b, 0) , (-c, 0)$
$3)$ Horizontal compression by a factor of 1/r:  $(-a/r, 0) , (-b/r, 0) , (-c/r, 0)$
$4)$ Horizontal translation t/r units left:  $(-a/r - t/r, 0) , (-b/r - t/r, 0) , (-c/r - t/r, 0)$

Am I correct?

zeroes of the newly transformed function are :
$$   
((-a/r  - t/r), 0), \space  
(-(b/r - t/r), 0), \space   
(-(c/r - t/r), 0)  $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.

Generally, suppose $g(x)=f(rx+t).$ Then $g(x)=0$ iff $f(rx+t)=0$ iff $rx+t=z$ for $z$ any zero of $f$. Then the zeros of $g$ are given by $\frac{z-t}{r}$ for $z$ any zero of $f$.